# Directive to redirect to an outlet

Tags: angular

I'm currently creating a modal features for my template taking profit of named outlet, until now I was manually writing my link to open the modal, but I would like to make it easier.

Current code :

```
<a [routerLink]="['', { outlets: { modal: ['upload'] }}]" [preserveQueryParams]="true">+</a>
```

Expected code:

```
<a [modal]="upload">+</a>
<button [modal]="upload">+</button>
```

How could I create something like this? I've see the nativeElement, but I don't think editing the `DOM` is the easiest solution to handle this.

Comment: You can just inject the Router and ActivatedRoute in your directive, and call one of the router functions to navigate to another route (needs the current route for relative navigation)

Comment: And bind it to the click event on the element?

Comment: exactly. You can use `@HostListener()`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Günter, I actually went with the click event. Here's my final code for the one whose encountered the same issue.

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[dialog]"
})
export class DialogDirective {
    @Input("dialog") dialog: string;

    public constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
    public onClick($event) {
        this.dialog = this.dialog || null;
        this.router.navigate(["", { outlets: { modal: this.dialog }}], { preserveQueryParams: true });
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

If I do not specify any element, then I'm just closing the current modal.